# Aid my use of generic data types

Tags: java, generics, types, primitive-types

Please help me. This is a homework assignment and I cannot figure out why it wont work. When I call the linear Search method it says I am not passing the correct data type of T. T should be a generic data type so I do not understand why it is giving me a hard time. Please help!

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] five= new int[5];
        int[] ten= new int[10];
        int[] fifteen= new int[15];
        fillArray(five);
        fillArray(ten);
        fillArray(fifteen);

        int result1 = linearSearch(five, 37);
        int result2 = linearSearch(ten, 37);
        int result3 = linearSearch(fifteen, 37);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(five) + " " + result1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ten) + " " + result2);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fifteen) + " " + result3);

    }
```

//This method performs the linear search on the filled arrays and has to accept all data types.

```
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int linearSearch(T[] array, T data){
        int value = -1;  
          for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            if (array[i]== data){
                value = i;
              }
          }
          return value;
        }
```

Comment: Generics don't work with primitive types.

Comment: Try using `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics don't work with primitive types.  You can only use actual objects.  And unfortunately, auto-boxing won't magically work in this scenario.

You can get this to work and continue to use generics by using the wrapper object, `Integer` (assuming your `fillArray` method will work with an `Integer` object, since it's not posted in your example).  e.g.,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] five = new Integer[5];
    Integer[] ten = new Integer[10];
    Integer[] fifteen = new Integer[15];

    fillArray(five);
    fillArray(ten);
    fillArray(fifteen);

    int result1 = linearSearch(five, 37);
    int result2 = linearSearch(ten, 37);
    int result3 = linearSearch(fifteen, 37);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(five) + " " + result1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ten) + " " + result2);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fifteen) + " " + result3);

}
```

If you're interested in some of the formal theory, you can read more about type parameters in [JLS 4.5 - Parameterized Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5).  As you see in 4.5.1, it says that:

> Type arguments may be either reference types or wildcards.

... which implicitly excludes primitive types.  Couldn't find where in the JLS it actually explicitly forbids them, but I'm sure it's in there.

Comment: There is no unboxing. The return type of linearSearch is `int`, not `T` (however, I misread that in the same way as you did).

Comment: @aRestless Oh, right.  Durr.  I was looking at the `<T extends Comparable<T>>` like an idiot.  Haha

Comment: Believe it or not, though, I just tested it, and if you return something of type `T`, there's no compiler error generated if the return value is assigned to a primitive type.

Comment: Tried it out myself. Quite interesting that the mechanism for generics is that smart. However, it fails if you use an incompatible generic type, like in `Float[] array = {3.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f}; int i = linearSearch(array, 4.0f);`

Comment: This was what I was looking for! We were required in the assignment to use the Generic <T> and this answered the question exactly! Thanks I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @user3713393 Glad it helped you out. :)  Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with Generics, but you can with [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html)! Like so,

```
public static int linearSearch(Object array,
    Object data) {
  int len = Array.getLength(array);

  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (Array.get(array, i).equals(data)) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] five = new int[] { 1, 2, 37 };
  int[] ten = new int[] { 1, 37, 5 };
  float[] fifteen = new float[] { 1.0f, 2.2f, 0f, 4f };

  int result1 = linearSearch(five, 37);
  int result2 = linearSearch(ten, 37);
  int result3 = linearSearch(fifteen, 37);

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(five) + " "
      + result1);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ten) + " "
      + result2);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fifteen) + " "
      + result3);
}
```

And the output is,

```
[1, 2, 37] 2
[1, 37, 5] 1
[1.0, 2.2, 0.0, 4.0] -1
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm being dense, but I don't get what this has to do with reflection?  Nice auto-boxing solution, though.

Comment: @JeffGohlke `java.lang.reflect.Array`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Hm.  Interesting.  No idea why such a utility class would be classified under reflection.  I guess because of the instance allocation.  Cool! +1

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the kind of solution we should teach our programming apprentices...

Comment: @aRestless Is it better to say *no* that's impossible and there is no solution?

Comment: Agree with @aRestless. This is a very clever trick, but probably not a good example for a student. :)